# How to write a function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function

I want to write a function that returns the value of `f(y)` for any value of `y`:

```
f(y) =tan( sin(y) - sin(tan(y)) )
```

How can I write this as a function in MATLAB?

Comment: here is the relevant documentation page from the matlab website: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html

Comment: You can also create an anonymous function (a one line function, useful for very short function with only one output). With your example : `f = @(y) tan(sin(y) - sin(tan(y)))`, then it can be used with, for example, `f(pi/2)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example function for your purpose

```
function y = f(x)
   y = tan(sin(x)-sin(tan(x)));
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an anonymous function, as elluded to in the comments by 
[obchardon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59262733/how-to-write-a-function-in-matlab#comment104736697_59262733):

```
f = @(y) tan(sin(y) - sin(tan(y)))

% usage like any other function:
f(1)
```

Note that you **do not** include the `(y)` on the left hand side of the `=`, this syntax is reserved for [indexing into variables](https://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html), or [symbolic math](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-numbers-variables-and-expressions.html).